# New Instance of object skipping overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, edmx

Using vs2012, I've got a Test Unit project (for testing a Service) that incorporates an .edmx file and linq.  The edmx is created at design time and I have created an object (called Store.Data.Common) that retrieves the connection string from the App.Config file (decrypts the string and builds the entire string including the meta data):

```
//Object is called Store.Data.Common
public static string GetConnectionString(string databaseName)
{
    var security = new Security();

    var connectionString = security.GetDecoded(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[databaseName+"Encrypted"].ToString(), 0);
    var environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"].ToString();
    var dataSource = security.GetDecoded(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[environment], 0);

    connectionString = string.Format(connectionString, dataSource);

    return connectionString;
}
```

I've also **modified the .tt files** to include an overload of the constructor to call this method to build the connection string, like so:

```
//Original Constructor which I modified and added the parameter to pass to the other constructor.
public StoreContext()
 : base("name=StoreContext")
{
}

//Constructor I added:
public StoreContext(string connection)
{
    Store.Data.Common.ConnectionBuilder.GetConnectionString("StoreContext");
}
```

Everything builds correctly, however, when I try to new-up an object for the StoreContext and leave the constructor empty, it never gets to the second constructor:

```
StoreContext storeContext = new StoreContext();
```

When I debug this test and walk through it, it only gets to the first constructor and that's it.  Obviously, if I do something like this:

```
StoreContext storeContext = new StoreContext("Blah");
```

Then it goes to the second one as expected....by my question is, why doesn't the first method work when passing nothing to the constructor?  Technically it should work, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to use

```
public StoreContext()
  : this("name=StoreContext")
{
}
```

(using `this` rather than `base`).

using `this()` means you're calling a constructor on the same class. When you say `base()` you're trying to call a constructor on the base class.

*Edit: It also doesn't look like you're using the parameter you're passing into that non-default constructor. But that's another issue, not the root of your problem.*

Comment: Too quick for me om my tablet! :)

Comment: @Tim making those changes worked, but when I try to query the data, I get an error 'Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.'

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the T4 templates and the Db First/Model First/Code first configurations. You might want to start a new question on that new error if you're not sure about it.